# Solving $\frac{x^{11}+x}{x^7+x^5}=\frac{205}{16}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Blockquote
> Find $x$ satisfy the equation$$\frac{x^{11}+x}{x^7+x^5}=\frac{205}{16}$$

Here is my work
$$\frac{x^{10}+1}{x^6+x^4}=\frac{205}{16},\quad\quad t:=x^2$$
$$\frac{t^5+1}{t^3+t^2}=\frac{205}{16}$$
$$16t^5-205t^3-205t^2+16=0$$
$t=-1$ is a root of the polynomial but not sure how to find the other roots.

Another approach I tried is dividing numerator and denominator of the original fraction by $x^6$,

$$\frac{x^5+\frac1{x^5}}{x+\frac1x}=\frac{205}{16}$$
$$x^4-x^2+1-\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{x^4}=\frac{205}{16}$$

Comment: Can you guess any solutions to the last equation? There are 4 values which are worth trying.

Comment: I see the $x^{10}+1$ in the numerator and wonder how it might relate to $205$. If $205$ comes from reducing a fraction, can we find some $10$th power (plus $1$) that is a multiple of $205$? The first $10$th power you might try is $2^{10}$. And it works: $\frac{2^{10}+1}{2^6+2^4}=\frac{205}{16}$. So by ad hoc thinking, one solution is $x=2$. Since the exponents are even, $x=-2$ works as well. And $t=4$ is one root, so you can reduce your 5th degree polynomial in $t$ to a 4th degree polynomial. And you also have $t=-1$, so further to a 3rd degree.

Comment: Also if $x$ is a solution, then so is $\frac{1}{x}$. Because $\frac{x^{10}+1}{x^6+x^4}=\frac{x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}}{x+\frac{1}{x}}$. So $x=\pm\frac12$ are two more solutions. With $t=\frac14$, now your $t$-polynomial can be reduced to a quadratic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

You are on the right track!

Notice that
\begin{align*}
x^{2} + \frac{1}{x^{2}} = \left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{2} - 2
\end{align*}

Similarly, we do also have that

\begin{align*}
x^{4} + \frac{1}{x^{4}} & = \left(x^{2} + \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)^{2} - 2\\\\
& = \left[\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{2} - 2\right]^{2} - 2
\end{align*}

Now you can make the substitution

\begin{align*}
u = x + \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}

Then we get that
\begin{align*}
[(u^{2} - 2)^{2} - 2] - (u^{2} - 2) + 1 = \frac{205}{16} \Longleftrightarrow u^{4} - 5u^{2} + 5 = \frac{205}{16}
\end{align*}

which is a biquadratic equation.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative from here we have

$$\frac{t^5+1}{t^3+t^2}=\frac{205}{16} \iff \frac{(t+1)(t^4-t^3+t^2-t+1)}{t^2(t+1)}=\frac{205}{16}$$

and since $t=x^2\ge 0$

$$\iff \frac{t^4-t^3+t^2-t+1}{t^2}=\frac{205}{16} \iff t^2-t+1-\frac1 t+\frac1{t^2}=\frac{205}{16}$$

$$\iff t^2+2+\frac1{t^2}-t-\frac1 t-\frac{221}{16}=0 \iff \left(t+\frac1t\right)^2-\left(t+\frac1t\right)-\frac{221}{16}=0$$

and by $u= t+\frac1t$ we obtain

> $$u^2-u-\frac{221}{16}=0$$